# how to make a condition to data from json

Tags: java, android, json

i want to make a condition when i call the json and make it to 'you cannot have the same thing' in the json value when you want to add more data to database.

this is my code

```
String nim2, ruang2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kelas);
    nim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNim);
    ruang = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ruangPinjam);

    new daftarMahasiswa().execute();
}

public void nextButton (View view) {
    nim2 = nim.getText().toString();
    ruang2 = ruang.getText().toString();
    if (ruang2.equals(ruangan)) {
        Toast.makeText(KelasActivity.this, "this room has already borrow",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ruang.setError("you cannot borrow the room again");
    }else if (nim2.equals(nimMahasiswa)){
        Toast.makeText(KelasActivity.this, "this NIM has borrow the room",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        nim.setError("you cannot borrow it again");
    }

class daftarMahasiswa extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(KelasActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String link_url = "http://192.168.43.54/datapeminjamankelas/read_mahasiswa.php";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                ruangan = ar.getString("ruang").trim();
                nimMahasiswa = ar.getString("nim").trim();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }    
}
```

and this is my json

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "nim": "103452",
      "ruang": "2702"
    },
    {
      "nim": "102341",
      "ruang": "2504"
    },
    {
      "nim": "103421",
      "ruang": "1101"
    }
  ]
}
```

what i want to make is the 'nim' and the 'ruang' from json cannot be add again with the same value. it works honestly but only when the data just have 1, when it have more it dont work anymore. please help what can i put to make it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 'nim' and 'ruang' values in separate List and from there, you can check whether the entered value is already present or not.

```
List<String> nimList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ruangList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
    ruangan = ar.getString("ruang").trim();
    nimMahasiswa = ar.getString("nim").trim();
    nimList.add(nimMahasiswa);
    ruangList.add(ruangan);
}
```

You can check like below:

```
    nim2 = nim.getText().toString();
    ruang2 = ruang.getText().toString();
    if (ruangList.contains(ruang2)) {
           Toast.makeText(KelasActivity.this, "this room has already borrow",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           ruang.setError("you cannot borrow the room again");
    }else if (nimList.contains(nim2)){
           Toast.makeText(KelasActivity.this, "this NIM has borrow the room",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           nim.setError("you cannot borrow it again");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you could have a pojo class and override equals method like below

```
public class MyData {
  private String myNim;
  private String myRuang;
  //setter & getters here
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceOf MyData)
    {
      MyData myData = (MyData) obj;
      return myData.getMyNim().equals(this.myNim)&&myData.getMyRuang().equals(this.myRuang);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and now you can check the element exist or not by using below code.

```
try {
  str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
  List<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
  for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
    ruangan = ar.getString("ruang").trim();
    nimMahasiswa = ar.getString("nim").trim();
    MyData myData = new MyData();
    myData.setMyNim(nimMahasiswa);
    myData.setMyRuang(ruangan);
    if(myDataList.contains(myData))
      //use your logic here to show error 'you cannot have the same thing'
    else
      myDataList.add(myData);
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

now you can use the myDataList which is having unique elements.